# How does Hibernate know which query cache to use?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, hibernate-4.x

When the using the JPA API backed by Hibernate with the query cache enabled, how does Hibernate know which query cache to use for a `java.persistence.Query` instance?

I've read that, to enable the query cache of `Query q`, you're supposed to call `q.setHint(“org.hibernate.cacheable”, true)`.

From what I know about JPA, however, you are supposed to obtain your `Query q` by calling `EntityManager#createQuery(String qlString)` every time that you need to run a query, instead of saving the returned `Query` to a variable and reusing it.  Thus, if you enable the query cache for a specific `Query` instance, but then discard it, how does Hibernate determine which cache to use for a newly created `Query`?  It could be based on:

1. case-sensitive string comparison of the `qlString` argument
2. case-insensitive string comparison of the `qlString` argument
3. comparison of some logical representation of the query (in this case, `"select t from table t where t.a = :a and t.b = :b"` would use the same query cache as `"select t from table t where t.b = :b and t.a = :a"`, whereas in the string comparison ways, the swapping of the order of the two where conditions would result in different query caches being used)
4. some other mechanism

As a contrast, in EclipseLink, you can only enable the query results cache for named queries, which can be obtained via the `createNamedQuery(String name)` or `createNamedQuery(String name, Class<T> resultClass)` methods.  In this case, it's obvious that the query results cache that is uses is determined by the value of `name` passed to the `createNamedQuery` method.

Comment: Why is that so important to you?